# Is there a way to reliably reproduce ASP.NET's generation of client-side validation?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, webforms

I'm on just a bit of a journey here. I can create server controls, validation controls, custom validators, etc. and add them to a page. What I'm curious about is if it's possible to hoist a custom validator 100% client-side without the use of `<asp:________Validator />`.

For example, if I simply placed a:

```
<span id="some_custom_id">* REQUIRED!</span>
```

Is it possible to wire that in the global/window object as a validator?

For example, on the window object you can see the collection of validators via:

```
> Page_Validators
>> Array[2]
>>> 0: span#someid
>>> 1: span#anotherid
>>>>>>: controltovalidate: "idofthecontrol"
>>>>>>: validationGroup: "validationGroupOfControl"
>>>>>>: evaluationfunction: RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid(val)
```

My reasons are for a deeper understanding of how asp.net is creating the client-side validation. I've generated a custom validation object and pushed it to the array of validators, but it breaks nearly everything else in the validation. I'm also wondering if the asp.net scripts are being dynamically generated to handle/house the functions for different types of validations - as in I can't rely or assume that the appropriate validation methods will be available for me to just tie into.

It would be cool to push these validators/messages to the validation summary control. I understand server-side validation is needed, but that isn't the point of the question.

Another way to look at this is creating a dynamic set of form fields with JavaScript, all on the client, or swapping out, changing what's required and what's not based on selections, all of which ties into the validation summary.

I can do this with plenty of workarounds, and piggy back the Page_Validate method, but it doesn't feel optimal. As in I can create custom validation methods and intercept the form submission... no problem. I just want to find a way to properly manipulate the page validators on the global object and keep everything simplified.

Since I'm monkeying around in new lands, I'm more interested in if anyone has done this, is it reasonably possible, and perhaps pointing me in the right direction.